# AOSP - Adding Default Wifi SSID

Tags: android, android-source

I am building my fork of AOSP (Android Open Source Project).

I am trying to figure out how to add Wifi Configuration to the build.
So once I flash onto a device that it already has the SSID/WEP Key set.

I've looked in the default configuration here:

```
/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsProvider/res/values/defaults.xml 
/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml
```

But I cannot find anything related to Wifi SSID/Key.

Comment: The wifi configurations get converted to entries in `/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf`. When I figure out how to pre-load that file properly, I'll post the answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just FYI. If you are doing AOSP images and wanna add preinstalled accesspoints.
search wpa_supplicant-overlay.conf file (normally under /data/misc/wifi/) and add network information there. Then roll out the images. Tested with Marshmallow.

```
Example
network={
    ssid="test_wlan1"
    psk="test_key1"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    priority=1
}

network={
    ssid="test_wlan2"
    psk="test_key2"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    priority=2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Never found a way to directly include Wifi Configuration, but I created a seperate application that calls

```
public void saveWepConfig(String SSID, String Password, boolean Hidden)
    {
        WifiConfiguration wfc = new WifiConfiguration();

        wfc.SSID = "\"".concat(SSID).concat("\"");
        wfc.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.DISABLED;
        wfc.priority = 40;
        wfc.hiddenSSID = Hidden;

        wfc.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        wfc.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        wfc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
        wfc.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.SHARED);
        wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
        wfc.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
        wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
        wfc.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);

        if (isHexWepKey(Password)) wfc.wepKeys[0] = Password;
        else wfc.wepKeys[0] = "\"".concat(Password).concat("\"");
        wfc.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;

        WifiManager wfMgr = (WifiManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        int networkId = wfMgr.addNetwork(wfc);
        if (networkId != -1) {
         // success, can call wfMgr.enableNetwork(networkId, true) to connect
            wfMgr.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
        }

    }

    private boolean isHexWepKey(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            return false;
        }

        int len = s.length();
        if (len != 10 && len != 26 && len != 58) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')) {
                continue;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define your network inside:

```
system/etc/wifi/wpa_supplicant_overlay.conf
```

Which can be found in AOSP path under:

```
device/.../wpa_supplicant_overlay.conf
```

And inside this file you can have the network configuration, for example:

```
network={
    ssid="my wifi name"
    psk="my password here"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    priority=42
}
```

After rebooting the device, if the configuration is valid, it will copy it with more network configuration into:

```
/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

---

Another approach is to add the network programmatically.

Comment: Hi, I found six wpa_supplicant_overlay.conf files under /device/.. in different paths. In which one should i add the network configurations?i did search for the file under device sindce the complete path is not mentioned here. and it will be good if someone can share the the  wpa_supplicant_overlay.conf after adding configurations so that i can get to know where to add

Answer (score 0):

WPA solution based on @Carsten's solution:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

.

```
public static void saveWpaConfig(Context context, String SSID, String Passphrase, boolean Hidden)
{
    WifiManager wfMgr = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    // Turn on WiFi if necessary
    if (!wfMgr.isWifiEnabled())
        wfMgr.setWifiEnabled(true);
    // Do not continue if we can't get into a good state or
    // if this device already has at least one WifiConfiguration
    List<WifiConfiguration> cfgList = wfMgr.getConfiguredNetworks();
    if (!wfMgr.isWifiEnabled() || cfgList == null || cfgList.size() > 0)
        return;

    WifiConfiguration wfc = new WifiConfiguration();
    wfc.SSID = "\"".concat(SSID).concat("\"");
    wfc.preSharedKey = "\"".concat(Passphrase).concat("\"");
    wfc.hiddenSSID = Hidden;

    int networkId = wfMgr.addNetwork(wfc);
    if (networkId != -1) {
        wfMgr.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
        // Use this to permanently save this network
        // wfMgr.saveConfiguration();
    }
}
```